# ignore spacy deprecation_warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

Is there a way to avoid calling `deprecation_warning` in `spacy` from the code ?

I tried doing the following but that doesn't help :

```
import warning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: try this `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: doesn't work, i am running pyinstrument on the code and i see deprecation_warning function calls taking a significant amount of time .

Comment: If the warning is raised by spaCy, it should have a code – e.g. `W001`. You can then set the `SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE` environment variable to only ignore that specific warning (or several comma-separated codes) – for example, `SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE=W022`.

Comment: @RameshK How did you suppress the error. I am also facing same problem. Where should one make changes to that is suggested by Ines. I could find the code errors.py (link here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/68900066e060b6e2fd7b74e343e6b4c93d8d96c2/spacy/errors.py#L460) but not sure where exactly to set the "SPACY_WARNING_IGNORE=W022"